# Incorrect derived query for byId in Spring Data Neo4j

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have two entities: User and Connection, along with two appropriate repositories. Both entities has `@GraphId id` field. Connection entity has `User user` field.

In ConnectionRepository interface I added following method:

```
List<Connection> findByUserId(long userId)
```

But it doesn't work. It generates incorrect cypher query. I think it incorrect, because it contains clause like this:

```
WHERE user.id = 15
```

which is not working, because `id` is not a property. It must be:

```
WHERE id(user) = 15
```

**Is this a bug? In any case, how can I get it to work?**

Comment: which version of spring-data-neo4j are you using ?

Comment: I use milestone release candidate 4.0.0.RC2

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll transfer to the right people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The derived query translates to the property `id` of the `user` defined on the `Connection`. It is quite possible that node entities contain a user managed `id` property as well and it would be incorrect to assume that `id` is always the node id.

In this case, you might want to use a `@Query` instead.

```
@Query("MATCH (user:label) WHERE ID(user)={0} return user")
List<Connection> findByUserId(long userId)
```

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Currently I already used this workaround. But I thought, there are special means to do that.

Comment: There's the repo.findOne that takes a node ID, but of course, that will just give you the single node that matches this id. Not useful for querying with other conditions involved

Comment: Method repo.findOne is not suitable not only because it is not useful for querying with other conditions, but mainly because it searches one entity by its id instead of search list of entities by id of related entity (in my case, user has relation to connection).